# Has anyone ever used the Image-science gem for generating thumbnails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-science

It appears to be what I need (just basic thumbnail generation magic) and according to its ruby-toolbox description, it "kicks the living crap out of RMagick."

I'd appreciate any sort of feedback on this gem.  And yes, I'm evaluating it on my own as well.

Comment: why don't you use `mini_magick`?

Comment: no particular reason :) I'll take a look at that as well...